# Why does my app flutter can't download the dependencies?

Tags: flutter

I can't debug my application.
First, the error happened when downloading the gradle, I managed to solve it, downloading manual and pointing to local file, but after that started to happen the error in other dependencies, 
It's like I'm using proxy, but I'm not using proxy.
I've tried changing the version of gradle and all the other tips I've seen on the internet but nothing works.
I'm using the latest version of android studio on a macbook
the error message always relates to UnknownHostException.

Comment: share the entire error message

Comment: Does your problem only occur on Android builds or does it affect iOS as well?

Comment: only android builds

Comment: the error is Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org